# Angularjs Typeahead Directive - error: ''Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead, angular-ui-typeahead

I am using the Angularjs Bootstrap Typeahead directive and running into an error that says the following:

Error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
at ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.1.min.js:9
at angular.min.js:112
at l.$get.l.$eval (angular.min.js:125)
at l.$get.l.$digest (angular.min.js:122)
at l.$get.l.$apply (angular.min.js:126)
```

Below Is My HTML

```
<h4>Asynchronous results</h4>
<pre>Model: {{asyncSelected | json}}</pre>
<input type="text" ng-model="asyncSelected" placeholder="Patients loaded via $http" typeahead="result as result.patient.drug.drugindication for result in getPatient($viewValue)" typeahead-loading="loadingPatients" class="form-control">
<i ng-show="loadingPatients" class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i>
```

Javascript

```
$scope.getPatient = function(val) {
return $http.get('https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json', {
  params: {
    search: 'patient.drug.drugindication:' + val
  }
}).then(function(response){
  return 
  { 
    search: response.data
}
});
};
```

Codepen 
    http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XJBNEq?editors=101

Comment: Do you have any plnkr/fiddle for this?

Answer (score 2):

You just have to return the promise itself. Don't use the .then()

```
    $scope.getPatient = function(val) {
return $http.get('https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json', {
  params: {
    search: 'patient.drug.drugindication:' + val
  }
})
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your val received in the `getPatient()` and your function can return null value. so when the typeahead is calling `length`property on a null object. I think you can fix it by adding a check before calling the webservice and returning an empty array when input is null.

```
$scope.getPatient = function(val) {
if(!val) { //directly return an empty array if val is null, or empty string
    return [];
}

return $http.get('https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json', {
  params: {
    search: 'patient.drug.drugindication:' + val
  }
}).then(function(response){
  return 
  { 
    search: response.data
}
});
};
```

Comment: Mathieu, I tried your solution, however it didn't work. Same error

Comment: Can you do a plunkr or something like this ?

Answer (score 0):

I write code which works to me. $http restuns promise which result should be written to your controllers scope.

```
$scope.getPatient = function(val) {
var data = $http.get('https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json', {
  params: {
    search: 'patient.drug.drugindication:' + val
  }
});
data.then(function(response){
    if ( response.data != null ) 
        $scope.asyncSelected = response.data;
    else
        $scope.asyncSelected = [];
});
};
```

Take care of resulting empty result. 
Also set correct name in scope. 
If data doesn't change, set $watch for asyncSelected. 
How do you search for params?
Usually you send params not like:

```
search: 'patient.drug.drugindication:' + val
```

but

```
'patient.drug.drugindication': + val

params { 
key: value,
key2: value2
}
```

Comment: Cyan thanks for your response but I still get the same error :( it has something to do with angular bootstrap because the error says "at ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.1.min.js:9"

Answer (score 0):

You're forgetting

```
return data;
```

in

```
$scope.getPatient = function(val) {

    var data = $http.get('https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json', {
          params: {
            search: 'patient.drug.drugindication:' + val
      }
    });
    data.then(function(response){
        $scope.gotresults = response.data.results;
        console.log($scope.gotresults)
        if ( response.data != null ) {
            $scope.asyncSelected = response.data.results;
        }
        else {
            $scope.asyncSelected = [];
        }
    });

  return data;
};
```

`

[Updated Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qEGzwa?editors=101)